# Problems with storing data into the array

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

My programs allows user to delete specify records when they input a username. When they pass in the name, it will invoke a method which will store them into a array, and write them back to the file without appending, so as to re-write the file.
But there is some problem during the storing part where my last line of the textfile is not stored properly, and instead it copy from the 2nd last line and copy to the last line with the name included.
Hopefully no1 will get confuse :/. The example of the textfile and data stored inside my array is below which i make bold and italic for clearer picture, and also method for the deleteRec.

This is what my textfile contains.

```
user;pass;1234;John;1111
user1;pass1;2345;May;2222
user2;pass2;3456;Mary;3333
user3;pass3;4567;Andy;4444
hr;hr;5678;Jonathan;5555
admin;admin;6789;Aili;6666
user10;pass10;7890;eggy;9999
user11;pass11;9807;Mary;7777
```

This is my output when i run my program to delete.

```
Data stored in store[] array: user1;pass1;2345;May;2222
Data stored in store[] array: user2;pass2;3456;Mary;3333
Data stored in store[] array: user3;pass3;4567;Andy;4444
Data stored in store[] array: hr;hr;5678;Jonathan;5555
Data stored in store[] array: admin;admin;6789;Aili;6666
Data stored in store[] array: user10;pass10;7890;eggy;9999
***Data stored in store[] array: ;pass10;7890;eggy;9999***
Data stored in store[] array:
```

```
bool Employee::deleteRec(string nm)
{
    int count;
    int i=0;//for looping
    ifstream file("login1.txt");
    string fusername,empty;
    string store[100];//initialize a array to store textfile contents
    while (!file.fail()) 
    {       
        getline(file,fusername,';');// use ; as delimiter
        getline(file,empty);// use line end as delimiter, and to skip the rest of the information
        string add="";//initialize add string to nothing when it loops
        add += fusername+';'+empty; //adds back the username and rest of the line together back
        if(fusername!=nm)//to check if the username in textfile do not match the user input name
        {
            store[i]=add; //store into an array
            cout<<"i is: "<<i<<endl;
            cout<<"store array[] = "<<store[i]<<endl;
            i++;
        }
        else{}
    }

    //ofstream pwd2_file ("login1.txt", ios::app); //suppose to user this if im writing to file

    for(int x=0;x<i+1;x++)
    {
        cout<<"Data stored in store[] array: "<<store[x]<<endl;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: One thing, don't use e.g. `while (!file.fail())`. Use `while (getline(...))` instead.

Comment: @joachim-pileborg so will this work while((getline(cin,nm)) ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your loop is that when you reach end of file, your stream will not have failed yet. It only fails on the next read but you are not verifying this.

Therefore your array is containing the last record twice.

That you have an empty string as the first field could be because it set this one empty to read into it, (stream wasn't yet in a failed state) or because there was an empty line at the end of your input file which got read in.

Create a struct for your user and its data, and read in from the stream. If the whole of this read succeeds, you can append to your dataset.

I would suggest you use `std::vector` for this and `push_back()`.

The correct way to loop is as follows:

```
struct EmployeeData
{
    std::string name;
    // fill in members
;

std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, EmployeeData& emp )
{
     std::getline( is, emp.name(), ';' );
     // etc.

     return is;
}

std::vector< EmployeeData > emps;
EmployeeData emp;
while( is >> emp )
{ 
   emps.push_back( emp );
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do the loop instead than??

Comment: In your case since you do two getlines each time round the loop `while (getline(...) && getline(...)) {`. I'm just amazed, I really am.

Comment: @cashcow actually i have a class which string name is inside already, but i think with class im still able to do the same thing as what you are doing?

Comment: I used struct and public members to make it simpler. You can use class and private members but have to then make operator>> a friend. I actually prefer to use struct and public members for this purpose as it happens, then put a member of the struct into a class as a private data member if I want to add functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a debugger and just figure out what is getting passed over. Looks like an off by one error either in where the output is stored in the array, or when it is rewritten to the file. Would explain your lack of boundary users.